# What is the finite Morse index solution?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, morse-theory

I'm dealing with an elliptic PDE, it depends on the dimension of the domain, for some situations, I highly doubt that there is no $C^2$ solution, so I searched for some papers related to this equation and found that there are papers proving **no finite Morse index solution**, I want to ask that:

1.What is the difference between no classical solution and no finite Morse index solution?

2.If there are infinite Morse index solutions, what this infinite Morse index solutions look like?

In fact, I'm reading this paper [ON THE CLASSIFICATION OF SOLUTIONS OF $-\Delta u=e^u$ ON $\mathbb{R}^N$ : STABILITY OUTSIDE A COMPACT SET AND APPLICATIONS](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2009-137-04/S0002-9939-08-09772-4/S0002-9939-08-09772-4.pdf), it states that let $3 \leq N \leq 9$. Equation $$
-\Delta u=e^u \quad \text { on } \mathbb{R}^N, \quad N \geq 2,
$$ does not admit any $C^2$ solution stable outside a compact set of $\mathbb{R}^N$.

When $N=2$, there is a celebrated paper written by Congming Li and Wenxiong Chen, [Classification of solutions of some nonlinear elliptic equations](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Wenxiong-Chen/publication/38333132_Classification_of_solutions_of_some_nonlinear_elliptic_equations/links/09e415126d86fa7bf2000000/Classification-of-solutions-of-some-nonlinear-elliptic-equations.pdf), after reading this I began to be interested in the higher dimension case so I found the paper I mentioned I'm reading.

Comment: I mean, any useful answer to this would have to be context-dependent (and little context is provided here). Morse index is most easily understood in the context of variational problems where you are looking at critical points: it refers to the number of directions you can perturb the functional to decrease the energy, typically at the level of the second variation. A $0$ Morse index solution would be a stable one (e.g. a local min); finite Morse index ones have a finite number of unstable perturbations (e.g. mountain pass/saddle solutions), and infinite Morse index are the rest.

Comment: By itself, Morse index does not say anything about the shape of the solution. But in particular contexts it might restrict the geometry, induce some sort of finite symmetries, constrain behavior at infinity or at singularities, count sign changes or nodal domains, etc.